# Is it valid to reference a foreign key but it is not a primary key in other table?

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key, entity-relationship

I got 3 tables, (1) HOSPITAL table with a primary key HOS_ID, (2) CLINIC table with a primary key CLINIC_IDNO, and (3) DOCTOR table with a primary key DOC_IDNO and a 2 foreign keys (a) HOS_ADDRESS from HOSPITAL table and (b) CLINIC_ADRESS from CLINIC table. Is it a valid foreign keys? How or why is it valid? This is from a "ONLINE CONSULTATION SYSTEM ENTITY RELATIONSHIP DIAGRAM".

Comment: I don't see how it would be a problem. a primary key only serve to uniquely identify an entity. This entity may have other fields which are unique, like a serial number, a national number, etc. But for simplicity you prefer to handle custom IDs instead of a series of characters that are outside your comprehension. For a example a serial number could contain some business information, but for testing purpose, it's easier to work with a random integer that would serve as an ID.

Comment: "(a) HOS_ADDRESS from HOSPITAL table". A foreign key is a `REFERENCE` from one table to another. So is something referencing `HOS_ADDRESS` or is that referencing something? It's typical in large applications to put things like addresses in a separate reference table -- because for example a hospital might be spread over several sites (several addresses) and/or a clinic might be co-located with a hospital. So is there a `ADDR_ID` or similar?

Comment: Hospital and clinic has primary key: hos_id and clinic_id respectively. Both has column hos_address and clinic_address respectively... So ur saying we r using hos_address to reference from hospital table because a hospital might have multiple branches, and hospital has only one primary key which is hos_id. It is better to use its address as reference to precisely know what and where the hospital the doctor is working. Is it?